# Positioning TikZ block centrally above two child blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, nodes

I have the following MWE of a Beamer slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,calc}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, >=latex',
      block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=28mm,align=center},]
    \node [block] (dose_reduction) {Dose reduction};
    \node [block, below left=of dose_reduction] (filtering) {Filtering techniques};

    % issues with either of these lines
    %\node [block, below right=of dose_reduction] (reconstruction) {Reconstruction techniques};
    \node [block, right=of filtering] (reconstruction) {Reconstruction techniques};

    \draw[->] (filtering) edge (dose_reduction);
    \draw[->] (reconstruction) edge (dose_reduction);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the upper box to be horizontally centered. Also, the distance from the left slide edge to the left box should be as large as the distance from the right slide edge to the right box. 
I tried two variants but none worked out.

[image: mwe]

Comment: Welcome to this part of the galaxy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to place the nodes `below right` and `below left` of the `.south` anchor of the upper node to centre the upper block relative to the lower ones.

To centre the upper block relative to the frame, it is probably easiest to draw the lower blocks first and then centre the upper block relative to the current bounding box.

I've also updated the syntax to use `arrows.meta` rather than the deprecated `arrows` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, >=Latex,
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=28mm,align=center},]
    \node [block] (dose_reduction) {Dose reduction};
    \node [block, below left=of dose_reduction.south] (filtering) {Filtering techniques};
    \node [block, below right=of dose_reduction.south] (reconstruction) {Reconstruction techniques};
    \draw[->] (filtering) edge (dose_reduction);
    \draw[->] (reconstruction) edge (dose_reduction);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, >=Latex,
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=28mm,align=center},]
    \node [block] (filtering) {Filtering techniques};
    \node [block, right=of filtering] (reconstruction) {Reconstruction techniques};
    \node [block, above=of filtering.north -| current bounding box.center] (dose_reduction) {Dose reduction};
    \draw[->] (filtering) edge (dose_reduction);
    \draw[->] (reconstruction) edge (dose_reduction);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The picture in both slides is centred relative to the frame using `\centering`.
The first frame centres the upper block relative to the lower blocks.

[image: centred node relative to blocks]

The second frame centres the upper block relative to the frame.

[image: centred node relative to frame]

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful! However, the upper box is still not horizontally centered wrt the frame. Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: I assumed you wanted it centred with respect to the other boxes so that it looked symmetrical. I guess not?

Comment: Ya, I agree! Thanks again for the quick help :)

Comment: @pylipp See above for the other way as well. Personally, I think the second version looks ugly ;), but at least you know how to do it if you need to!

Comment: Oh, thanks! Indeed, I like the first version better, too. Maybe making the left box as wide as the right one solves all symmetry issues but again, I have no idea how to achieve that^^.

Comment: `text width=<some dimension sufficient for the widest text>` ?

Comment: Perfect, got it!